# Returning from a function with incompatible return type int **

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I have an exam and the teacher want to do a problem. It sound like this.
a)Reading information about an array (the function returns a structure associated with an array)
b)Reading the elements of an array (the function receives as parameters two integers and a pointer to FILE and returns a pointer to pointer to integer)

the point a) is Matrix* infoM.
the point b) is int** readM
And I get an error with the returning type

```
enter code here
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Matrix{
     int rows;
     int cols;
     int** data;
}Matrix;
Matrix* infoM( int n_rows, int n_cols)
{Matrix Matrix;
int i;
     Matrix.rows = n_rows;
     Matrix.cols = n_cols;
     Matrix.data = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n_rows);
     if(Matrix.data == 0)
     {
     fprintf(stderr, "err");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }
             for(i=0;i<n_rows;i++)
             {
             *(Matrix.data+i) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*n_cols);
                     if(*(Matrix.data+i) == 0)
                     {
                     fprintf(stderr,"err");
                     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                     }
             }

             struct Matrix *m;
             m = &Matrix;
return m;
}
int** readM(int n_rows, int n_cols, FILE *in)
{
Matrix* matrix = infoM(n_rows,n_cols);
int i,j;
     for(i=0; i<n_rows; i++)
     {
             for(j=0; j<n_cols; j++)
             {
             fscanf(in, "%d",*(matrix->data+i)+j);
             }
     }
return matrix;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The message in your title is not your only problem. `m = &Matrix;` You are returning the address of a local variable. That variable will not be valid any more after returning from your function. Accessing that memory causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Hm, ok, and how should I resolve this?

Comment: This is clearly pure C code not C++.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/cqxEdTcvr

Comment: I don't understand thet godbolt.org link

Comment: First, you need to indent your code consistently - sloppy indentation makes code hard to read.  And if you're sloppy when you're writing it, you're likely sloppy when you're thinking about what your code is doing. There's a reason why you never see code like that in professional-level work.  Second, `*(Matrix.data+i)` is more easily read as `Matrix.data[i]`.

Comment: The issue with returning addresses of local objects is typically solved in 3 ways: 1) Return a copy of the variable instead of a pointer to it. 2) Allocate dynamic memory and return that address. This requires to free the memory later. 3) Use an object with static lifetime and return its address. That will reduce usability as it is threadsafe and also overwrites the content between calls within the same thread.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a flexible array member to remove double-pointer - and additional overhead (it removes one level of indirection). Additionally, it simplifies malloc/free (only one needed).

To access data use an array pointer.

```
typedef struct Matrix{
     size_t rows;
     size_t cols;
     int data[];
}Matrix;

Matrix *createM(size_t rows, size_t cols)
{
    Matrix *m = malloc(sizeof(*m) + cols * rows * sizeof(m -> data[0]));
    return m;
}

Matrix *initM(Matrix *m)
{
    int (*data)[m -> cols] = (int (*)[m -> cols])m -> data; 

    for(size_t row = 0; row < m -> rows; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < m -> cols; col++)
        {
            data[row][col] = rand();
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Use correct types for sizes.

Answer (score 0):

C has a notion of lifetime for variables. Automatic variables (declared in a block of function) reach their end of life at the end of the block (or function...) where they are declared in. And using an object passed its end of life explicetely invokes Undefined Behaviour (close to hell for C programmers).

For that reason you cannot return the address of a local variable. It is called a *dangling* pointer (Google that word for additional details...).

But C allows to return a whole structure. So a minimal modification of your code could be:

```
...
Matrix infoM( int n_rows, int n_cols)
{Matrix Matrix;
int i;
     Matrix.rows = n_rows;
     ...
     return Matrix;
}
Matrix readM(int n_rows, int n_cols, FILE* in)
{
    Matrix matrix = infoM(n_rows, n_cols);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n_rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n_cols; j++)
        {
            fscanf(in, "%d", matrix.data[i] + j); // more C idiomatic...
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

For the same reason, `readM` is not allowed to return a pointer inside a local object, because it would be a dangling pointer, but you can again return the struct itself.